# NoMethodError in Users#show, undefined method `title' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000004c5e5f0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with my Rails blogging engine. Overall, the registration and creation of posts works (they form in the SQLite database), however when I attempt to list all the posts a user created, it throws a NoMethodError in User's show.html.erb view: undefined method 'title'.

**PostsController.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :user_is_required, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  def new
   @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    @post = user_logged_in.posts.create(post_params)
    if @post.save
    flash[:success] = "Your post has been successfully saved."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong. Try again."
      redirect_to new_post_path
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      flash[:success] = "Your post has been successfully updated."
      redirect_to post_path(@posts)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong. Try again."
      render 'post'
    end
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    if @post.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Your post has been successfully deleted."
      redirect_to posts_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Oops! Something went wrong. Try again."
    end
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb** (User's view)

```
<div class="posts">
  <div class="container marketing">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <section id="info">
            <%= image_tag("#", :class => "user_avatar") %>
            <h2 class="user_name">
                 <%= user_logged_in.name %>
            </h2>
        </section>
  <% if user_logged_in %>
    <%= link_to "Change avatar", class: "btn btn-primary" %><br>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h2>
            <%= user_logged_in.name %> has <%= user_logged_in.posts.count %> posts.
        </h2>
        <% if user_logged_in.posts.any? %>
            <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h2 class="title">
                <%= user_logged_in.posts.title %> # The line which raises the error
            </h2>
            <p class="post">
                <%= user_logged_in.posts.content %>
            </p>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

end
```

I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails and this is my first project. Any and all help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think the logic is a bit confused here.

`user_logged_in.posts` is a relation, so it returns the posts associated with the user that's logged in.
`@posts` is set t all the posts in the table.

```
<% if user_logged_in.posts.any? %>
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2 class="title">
      <%= user_logged_in.posts.title %> # The line which raises the error
    </h2>
    <p class="post">
      <%= user_logged_in.posts.content %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This says that if the logged in user has any posts, loop through all of the posts (not just the users posts), and then I think you want to display the users posts, but you're going wrong with syntax. Try changing your code as follows:

```
<% if user_logged_in.posts.any? %>
  <% user_logged_in.posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2 class="title">
      <%= post.title %>
    </h2>
    <p class="post">
      <%= post.content %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will loop through the users posts, assigning each post to the `post` variable, and then displaying the title and content of that post.

Comment: I tried the snippet you provided, but still does not work, the line: <% @user_logged_in.posts.each do |post| %> raises an error: "undefined method `posts' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Ok, now it works, albeit the posts are displayed as pure HTML. But that's an issue which I can solve. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`posts` should be `post` as you are inside loop i.e `<%= user_logged_in.posts.title %>` should be `<%= post.title %>` :

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <h2 class="title">
    <%= post.title %> # The line which raises the error
  </h2>
  <p class="post">
    <%= post.content %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Did not solve the problem, now it raises an error of "undefined method `post' for #<User:0x000000054cfc98>". What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: @DJ_Wilde Please check the edit.
The problem was you are trying to call `title` for a collection `@posts`, which you should do for individual instance rather i.e `post`. So, `post.title` would give you desired result.